# Decryption doesn't work and it gives Safe handle cannot be null error

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption

I have following code to encrypt a file when writing it to a file and decrypt a file when reading it. Although the encryption works without any visible issues, when I try to read the data by decrypting it gives me errors.

```
    public static LogManager CreateOrResumeManager(Table<LogPageIndex2> indexByRowIndex, Table<LogPageIndex2> indexByTimestamp, string filePath, LogData row, string password, bool encrypt = false)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        var logFileHeader = new LogFileHeader()
        {
            IsEncrypted = encrypt
        };
        var aesAlg = CreateEncryptor(password);

        var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();
        logFileHeader.IV = aesAlg.IV;

        var manager = new LogManager(row.TestRunId, row.RowIndex, filePath, indexByRowIndex, indexByTimestamp, logFileHeader)
        {
            Encryptor = encryptor
        };
        manager.WriteRow(row);
        manager.WriteLogHeader();
        manager.Close();
        return manager;
    }

    protected void WriteLogHeader()
    {
        _fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(_fileStream, LogFileHeader, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        _fileStream.Flush();
    }

    protected BinaryReader GetFile()
    {
        var file = File.Open(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var reader = new BinaryReader(file);
        return reader;
    }

    public bool TryReadRow(out LogData row)
    {
        try
        {
            using var reader = GetFile();
            var length = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            row = ReadRow(reader, length);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Tracer.Warning($"Could not read the row starting from the end: {e}");
            row = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected virtual LogData ReadRow(BinaryReader reader, int length)
    {
        if (Decryptor != null)
        {
            reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            var encryptedData = reader.ReadBytes(length);
            using var buffer = (RecyclableMemoryStream)Manager.GetStream(encryptedData);
            var bufferArray = buffer.GetBuffer();
            var decrypted = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bufferArray, 0, bufferArray.Length);
            return Serializer.Deserialize<LogData>(decrypted.AsSpan());
        }
        else
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<LogData>(reader.BaseStream, length: length);
        }
    }

    public static LogManager Load(string password, string filePath, Guid testRunId, int rowIndex)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Log file does not exist");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        {
            throw new Exception("Missing password");
        }
        
        var logFileHeader = ReadLogHeader(filePath);
        if (logFileHeader.IV == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Missing IV");
        }
        var aes = GetDecryptor(password, logFileHeader.IV);
        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
        var manager = new LogManager(testRunId, rowIndex, filePath, logFileHeader)
        {
            Decryptor = decryptor
        };
        manager.Close();

        return manager;
    }

    protected static LogFileHeader ReadLogHeader(string fileFullPath)
    {
        using var file = File.Open(fileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        return ReadLogHeader(file);
    }

    protected static LogFileHeader ReadLogHeader(Stream file)
    {
        if (file.Length >= 4)
        {
            using var reader = new BinaryReader(file);
            int length = reader.ReadInt32();
            file.Position = 0;
            var logHeader = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<LogFileHeader>(file, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
            logHeader.Length = length;
            if (file.Length == file.Position) logHeader.IsEmpty = true;
            return logHeader;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not read log file header");
        }
    }

    public static string GetAbsoluteFilePath(DirectoryInfo outputDirectory, string filename)
    {
        return Path.Combine(outputDirectory.FullName, $"{filename}{LogFileManager.DefaultLogFileEnding}");
    }

    public static string GetFileName(Guid runId, int rowIndex)
    {
        return $"{runId}_{TestRunSession.LogFileName}{rowIndex}";
    }

    public void WriteRow(LogData row)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, row);

            // Encrypt the data before writing it to the file
            var encryptedData = EncryptData(Encryptor, ms.ToArray());
            _fileStream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        }
        var tableLines = row.TableLines.Values.ToList();
        _newIndices.AddRange(tableLines.Select(tableLine => new LogPageIndex2(_runId, TestRunSession.LogFileName, row.Timestamp.ToJsTimestamp(), _rowIndex, tableLine.LineIndex)));
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _fileStream.Dispose();
        Encryptor?.Dispose();
        Decryptor?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }

    public static Aes GetDecryptor(string password, byte[] iv)
    {
        using var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltBytes);
        var aesKey = rfc.GetBytes(16);
        var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Key = aesKey;
        aes.IV = iv;
        return aes;
    }

    public static Aes CreateEncryptor(string password, byte[]? iv = null)
    {
        using var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltBytes, 1000);
        var aesKey = rfc.GetBytes(16);
        var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Key = aesKey;
        if (iv != null) aes.IV = iv;
        return aes;
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptData(ICryptoTransform encryptor, byte[] input)
    {
        using var encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        if (encryptor == null) return encryptedStream.ToArray();
        using var cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return encryptedStream.ToArray();
    }
   
}
```

when writing into the file I use

```
var manager = LogManager.CreateOrResumeManager(LogIndexByRowIndex, LogIndexByTimestamp, path, data, encryptionPassword, true);
```

When reading;

```
using (var manager = LogManager.Load(encryptionPassword, filepath, testRunId, index))
{
    manager.TryReadRow(out data);
}
```

When I try to read the encrypted file it gives me an error; `SafeHandle cannot be null (parameter 'pHandle')`

This is the first time I'm working on this type of task. Does anyone of you have encountered similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You close the manager before returning it, thus probably nullifying its values:

```cs
        manager.Close();
        return manager;
```